# Get start date and end date in full calendar for a view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

How can I get the start and end time of visible days in fullcalendar?

I need it for use in another javascript instance. Is there some function like -

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar1'].fullCalendar('getView').visStart
```

?

Answer (score 1):

According to full-calendar documentation (jQuery plugin on on which the `uiCalendar` is based on) when you call `fullCalendar('getView')` you get back the [View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Object/) object with properties:

> *start*
> A Moment that is the first visible day.
>
> *end*
> A Moment that is the exclusive last visible day.

So you should be able to get start and end moments as follows:

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar1'].fullCalendar('getView').start
```

and

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar1'].fullCalendar('getView').end
```

Answer (score 1):

Following example shows fullcalendar in angular 2. Should be easily adaptable to your environment. You can use the "viewRender" callback of fullcalendar to maintain the current visible date range. Useful if you intend to fetch business objects only relevant for the visible date range, etc.

```
var calendarDiv: any;
var self = this;

calendarDiv = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#calendar');
calendarDiv.fullCalendar({
        defaultView:    "agendaWeek",
        ...
        viewRender: function (view: any, element: any) {
            self.crtCalendarStart = view.start;
            self.crtCalendarEnd = view.end;
            self.myFilterService.setFilter("filter_plandate", {
                type:   'DateTime',
                value_from: view.start.toDate(),
                value_to: view.end.toDate()
            });
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: false,
        ...
      });
```